# applescriptを使ってQuickTime Playerでムービーの再生・停止を制御したい

Tags: applescript

applescriptを使ってQuickTime Playerでの再生・停止を制御したいと考えています．
具体的には，ムービーファイルを開き，再生を開始したい時刻と停止したい時刻（もしくは再生秒数）を取得し，その時刻情報で再生・停止する（そしてその範囲でループできるとなおよい）スクリプトを書こうとしています．

以下のように書いてみたのですが，停止の制御の仕方がわかりません．

```
display dialog "set file location:" default answer ""
set fileName to text returned of result as string
display dialog "set start time (seconds):" default answer ""
set startTime to text returned of result as integer
display dialog "set end time(seconds):" default answer ""
set endTime to text returned of result as integer
-- display dialog "set duration(seconds):" default answer ""
-- set playTime to text returned of result as integer

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set tDoc to open fileName
    tell tDoc
        set the presenting to true
        set the looping to true
        play
    end tell
end tell
```

上記のコードは見よう見まねで書いたものなので，`tDoc`の意味もわかっていません．
どうぞご回答をいただけますと幸いです．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんなスクリプトでいかがでしょうか？
最初のファイルロケーションは確認しておらず、開かれたドキュメントに対してループさせるところまで作ってみました。
つまり、`set tDoc to open fileName`の所を、事前にファイルを開いた`QuickTimePlayer`に対し、`set tDoc to document 1`で代用してしまいました。

ちなみに、`tDoc`は、開かれたドキュメントオブジェクトを保存する、自分で設定した変数名ですね。`startTime`や`endTime`と同じです

```
display dialog "set file location:" default answer ""
set fileName to text returned of result as string
display dialog "set start time (seconds):" default answer ""
set startTime to text returned of result as integer
display dialog "set end time(seconds):" default answer ""
set endTime to text returned of result as integer
-- display dialog "set duration(seconds):" default answer ""
-- set playTime to text returned of result as integer
display dialog "set loop count" default answer 1
set loopCount to text returned of result as integer

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set tDoc to open fileName
    tell tDoc
        repeat while (loopCount > 0)
            set the presenting to true
            set the looping to true
            set current time to startTime
            play
            repeat while (current time < endTime)
                delay 1
            end repeat
            set loopCount to (loopCount - 1)
        end repeat
        stop
    end tell
    close tDoc
end tell
```

Comment: 動きました！ループ回数の指定（およびループの止め方）は後回しと思っていたところでしたので，質問のさらに先までお教えいただいて感謝にたえません．

Comment: 差し支えありませんでしたら，ふたつのrepeatについてもう少し伺ってもよろしいでしょうか．外側のrepeatブロックは設定したループ回数について，一回処理を終えるごとに数字をひとつ減らして，最後ゼロになったらループを抜けるという記述かと思います．一方，内側のrepeatは，current timeがendTimeに達してから1秒待つ，ということで合っていますでしょうか？

Comment: はい。仰るとおりです。movieを制御するためのキーとなるプロパティがcurrent timeで、そこに値をセットすることで、再生開始時間を指定しています。そして、current timeを読み出すと現在の再生時間(先頭からの経過時間)が入っているので、endTimeと比較してオーバーしていなければ、delayコマンドで、時間を待ちます。今は1秒待っていますが、刻みを小さくすればその分スクリプトが消費するCPUは増えますが、オーバーランする時間が少なくなるという仕組みです。

Comment: ちなみに経過時間で指定したい場合は、set endTime to startTime + durationにすると動くと思います